# Equation to Draw Curves with Saturation and Peak

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-curves

I am looking for an equation to draw a graph like this:

[image]

The curve should have a peak and saturation.

Would you please let me know what is the equation that can generate similar curve ?

Here is the sample Excel file I have created to draw this curve but was not very successful to create the peak.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2171780/Book1.xlsx

Comment: Is the horizontal line $v = v_\text{peak}$ an asymptote, or does the curve touch this line for some value of $E$?

Comment: @bubba Curve just touch this line for some value of E.

Comment: @Variable , I have found that, however for any given value of u and V_sat I cannot create such a curve with peak. I can only create a curve with no peak.

Comment: @Variable , would you please take a look at the excel file I have placed in the original question? I need to draw a clean line for publication. The excel file has the Physical circuits formula and the curve. Not sure how to put the numbers in curve to create the peak. Thanks

Comment: So you have a function with two conditions. For e<e_peak, the function is similar to y=-x^2 (with some coefficients and offsets) and for e>e_peak, the function is similar to y=e^-x (again with some offsets)

Comment: I doubt if there is a single function for that.